# splitting of email-address in spark-sql

Tags: sql, database, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

code:

case when length(neutral)>0 then regexp_extract(neutral, '(.*@)', 0) else '' end as neutral

The above query returns the output value with @ symbol, for example if the input is 1234@gmail.com, then the output is 1234@. how to remove the @ symbol using the above query. And the resulting output should be evaluated for numbers, if it contains any non-numeric characters it should get rejected.

sample input:1234@gmail.com output: 1234
sample input:123adc@gmail.com output: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could phrase the regex as `^[^@]+`, which would match all characters in the email address up to, but not including, the `@` character:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(neutral, '^[^@]+', 0) AS neutral
```

Note that this approach is also clean and frees us from having to use the bulky `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
val pattern = """([0-9]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]+)""".r

val correctEmail = "1234@gmail.com"

val wrongEmail = "1234abcd@gmail.com"

def parseEmail(email: String): Option[String] = 
  
  email match {
    case pattern(id, domain) => Some(id)
    case _ => None
  }


println(parseEmail(correctEmail)) //  prints Some(1234)
println(parseEmail(wrongEmail)) // prints None
```

Also, it is more idiomatic to use `Option`s instead of `null`

Comment: The pattern """([0-9]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]+)""" is working for valid input but for invalid input it is returning splitted value like 678@gmail.com. The output should be null if the condition fails..With your condition, sample input: 1234abc789@gmail.com , output : 789@gmail.com.. It should return null if it has non-numeric value. @james

Comment: here is the query......case when length(neutral)>0 then regexp_extract(neutral,'([0-9]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]+)',0) else '' end as neutral  @james

Comment: @Vikram that regex pattern only works in Scala. It seems like your `regexp_extract` is from `apache-spark`. So please use it outside of spark as I have written for you, without the `regexp_extract` function. Returning `null` is also a bad practice in programming. Use `None` instead, then use the `.getOrElse`, `get`, `map`, or `foreach` functions to use the result.

Comment: @Vikram You can see the running [code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dH0sCVFrSpCI8OLZ5F1D1A) in here.